# Saving all Custom XIB Cell TableField Data into an Array

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView that displays a custom XIB cell repeated for all the data in an array I have. I also have a UIBarButton item that when pressed, adds a blank entry into that data array, which then creates a new blank cell. (Because numberOfRowsInSection returns [self.array count])

The XIB cell has a clear UITextField, so all cells are editable. The textfields, for each cell, displays that data in the array, for the appropriate index.

Now, what I'm trying to do is, when the UIBarButton item 'Save' is pressed, it gathers all of the data in the cells textfields, and basically saves it all into an array. I can't find a solution anywhere, so any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** I solved my own problem. For those wondering what to do:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < [self.dataArray count]; i++) {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0]];
    for (id subview in [cell.contentView subviews]) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)subview;
            self.updatedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:textField.text];
            NSLog(@"Cell Text: %@", self.updatedArray);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just loop through all the cells in a table view and add the contents of the text field to an array.

The example is assuming all the cells are in section 0 but you could change it to a nested loop with the number of sections playing a factor.

```
var saveData = [String]();
for i in 0..<tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0){
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: 0)) as! NameOfYourSubclassedCell;
    saveData.append(cell.textField.text);
}
```